# The roles of the layers in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I know that in MVVM, we want to propagate user input from the *view* to the *view model* via data binding, and give the reflected view state in the *view model* to the *model*, where we write the business logic code, and update the user with the result via events.
However, does it mean that every change in the view must be done outside of the xaml.cs file? 
Take for example a WPF application for [sliding puzzle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/15-puzzle.svg):
If we want to write an algorithm to solve the puzzle,  we'll put the code in the model. 
However, assume we want to update the grid after the user clicked the down key.
Checking if such move is possible, redrawing the board or giving the player any feedback (if the move is legit or no) should be done in the view? (the xaml.cs file) 
More generally, are there "rules of thumb" to decide what to handle where?

Comment: `However, does it mean that every change in the view must be done outside of the xaml.cs file?` The xaml.cs is part of the view layer. The viewmodel is in a separate file

Comment: *"Checking if such move is possible,  "* -- that's "business logic", so to speak. *"redrawing the board"* -- that's the view; it would do that in response to the viewmodel updating its abstract representation of the board. *"or giving the player any feedback (if the move is legit or no)"* -- the viewmodel would update some property, maybe a string property with an error message, which the view would display.

Comment: Questions involving correct use of MVVM can be asked in the [WPF Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf).

Comment: "If we want to write an algorithm to solve the puzzle, we'll put the code in the model." ==> no the model is just holding data, you have to create business classes that update the model=>viewmodel=>view

Answer (score 3):

Quick recap for the MVVM layers (or "rules of thumb"):

- **Model**: Contains only the data used by the view models. As an exemple, consider business objects coming from database as "models".
- **View**: Connection between the user and the view model. You can use multiple views for a same view model. If the view model changes and updates, the view should show the changes.
- **ViewModel**: Contains the "business logic" between the view and the model. As such, commands, possible actions and algorithms are stored here. The view model dictates what is possible and what is not.

The communication between layers needs (that's the part necessary for MVVM) to be *interchangeable*, meaning the view model can be used with differents compatibles views and the model can be used by differents compatibles view models. To cut down on the dependencies of the multiples layers: the layers *should not* communicate directly between them. We use commands, events and direct bindings.

> However, does it mean that every change in the view must be done outside of the xaml.cs file? [...] However, assume we want to update the grid after the user clicked the down key. Checking if such move is possible, redrawing the board or giving the player any feedback (if the move is legit or no) should be done in the view? (the xaml.cs file)

No. The view model should explicitly tell the view what is possible and what is not. The view shows that the action is possible or not: it does not **decide** if it is possible. Such decision is in the business logic, so in the view model.

As a trail of thoughts, take what it is said about *interchangeable* views. If you switch out the view `foo` for another view `bar` to show your puzzle and you did put the decision about "what's possible" in the view, you will have to rewrite the decision tree/algorithm in the new view `bar` and thus, duplication of code/logic.

When the decision is higher up, the view reflects what the view model is telling him. If the view model wants the view to "refresh" or to tell the user "hey, that's an illegal move", the view model will do so via [commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) and events. After receiving such events, the view could then decide what to do with it:

- Show an error message about the illegal move
- Show a tooltip that the move is illegal
- Flash and shake the window with a beep to show that the move is illegal
- Many more implementations...

I do hope I answered your question as thoroughly as possible.

Comment: _"ViewModel: Contains the "business logic" between the view and the view model."_... did you mean _"between the view and the **model**"_?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus: oops, my bad. That was a great catch!

Answer (score 1):

My 10 cents:

If my experience have taught me anything, it's that it's almost impossible to fit all problems with the same, general solution.

In the case of MVVM, some things I've learned (the hard way):

1. It's easy for the view model to devolve into God classes (ie, mix of purely view-related logic + some business logic + etc..)
2. Depending on the application tiers, some times it makes sense for logic to work on view models; other times, it's better for logic to work on the models instead.
3. Whatever layers I/you/anyone think certain classes/logic should go, will most likely have to change as development progresses.

Instead, my approach is usually:

1. Prepare

   - Model (for serialization, very little logic),
   - View Model (with property change bindings for view) and
   - View (thin layer, binds almost directly to View Model)
2. Write the majority of the application logic in the View Model.

   - Easier to have logic in here, so view bindings can work
   - This is the stage where the View Model layer bloats up
3. When the application is finally working, begin refactoring

   1. For rich-client applications, I find my Model classes to be almost purely data
   2. The View Model will most likely be refactored into 2 layers: MVM (Model-View-Model) and VVM (View-View Model)

      - MVM: This is where common, business-related logic/objects sit
      - MVM Objects contain truly common properties that any view can bind to
      - VVM: This is almost a 1-to-1 replication of a WPF view
      - These objects are typically never shared outside its own view
      - The separation into MVM and VVM helps prevent a single view model class from catering to ever views' needs (ie. whole bunch of `Is(Selected|Checked|etc)` and `*Command`, that may be only used exclusively by one view).
      - (For some people, VVM logic could probably be part of the View. But for me, I often find myself eventually wishing I had separated them in the first place, for testing. So now I do.)
   3. As the application evolves, properties/methods can be either pushed from the MVM into the VVM, or vice versa.

      - The application's hierarchy is almost never truly static.
      - Even when you build the best version of the application possible, the client will simply want more.

**Having the know-how to refactor an existing architecture to accommodate new requirements > Designing an architecture that is flexible enough for any future requirements**

*having said all that, for many applications that aren't too complex, a slightly-bulgy View Model is usually good enough.*

Comment: OMG this just seems horrible! A model-view-model and a view-view-model. Tell me your architecture is off the rails without telling me your architecture is of the rails.